# Base64(canvas) to blob, blob to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, canvas, blob

I have issue to send base64 image from canvas to PHP by using AJAX POST request. After i do some research on mr google, i found out alternative that people suggested to increase PHP server on php.ini etc memory_limit.. Maybe because of base64 length is too long and post method didn't worked.

Then, i use 2nd alternative is by using BLOB. I follow instruction from other stackoverflow author is to add function dataURItoBlob(). Looks like is working. But, the problem is, how i want to extract from blob files to base64 back in PHP? I tried several way, but no any result shown.

phpinfo.php

```
post_max_size = 999M;
memory_limit = 128M;
upload_max_filesize = 999M;
```

HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary btn-done" title="Save Image" type="button" id="saveimg" data="<?php echo $product_id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).delegate('#saveimg','click', function(event) {
   var outputType = '<?php echo $type ?>';
   var product = $(this).attr('data');

   myCanvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();

   var dataURL = myCanvas.toDataURL({
        format: 'jpg',
        quality:1,
        multiplier: canvas_multiply
   });

   var blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURL);
   var fi = new FormData();
   fi.append('imgBase64_0', blob, 'test.jpg');

   $.ajax({
      url: 'index.php?load=product/storeimg&p_id=' + product,
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: fi,
      success: function (json){
          // SOME CODE HERE //
      },
   });
});

function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
  var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
  var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
  var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
  var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);

  for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  var blob = new Blob([ab], {type: mimeString});
  return blob;
}
```

BLOB Array from print_r ($_FILES)

```
[files] => Array(
   [imgBase64_0] => Array
       (
           [name] => test.jpg
           [type] => image/jpeg
           [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpDpBZ0F
           [error] => 0
           [size] => 667026
        )
 )
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_FILES)) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $name => $value) {
         ${$name} = array(
              'name' => $value['name'],
              'type' => $value['type'],
              'tmp_name' => $value['tmp_name'],
              'error' => $value['error'],
              'size' => $value['size']
         );
    }

    if (is_dir($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name']) && is_writable($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'])) {
        $log = 'Writable and exist.'."\n";
    } else {
        $log = 'Not writable, or does not exist.'."\n";
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'], DIR_IMAGE)) {
        $txt .= "Successfully move.\n";
    } else {
        $txt .= "Fail to move.\n";
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: So the problem is within the PHP to store the file? What is `DIR_IMAGE`?

Comment: How is the canvas being generated originally and with what data?

Comment: @RamRaider sorry, my mistake didn't mention it. DIR_IMAGE is image directory

Comment: @RamRaider Canvas is generated from image editor which using myCanvas variable. Once user click id saveimg, myCanvas already capture data image. Hope i answer ur question. Sorry if i didnt

Comment: i hope my answer below helps answer your question above

Answer (score 1):

Saving a `canvas` generated image via ajax is quite straightforward so hopefully I understood your question correctly. Without knowing how the canvas is generated in your code nor the size of the image it is hard to say whether simply increasing file upload limits in PHP would solve the problem but if you look though the code below ( save & run as example with minor edit to save location ) you should find your solution is quite easy - hopefully!

For the demo, the image used was as shown below and saved locally to avoid using the url itself which leads to a warning

> Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases
>   may not be exported.

[image]

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['image'],$_POST['filename'] ) ){

        $image=$_POST['image'];
        $filename=$_POST['filename'];

        /* edit to suit own environment */
        $savepath='c:/temp/fileuploads/1/';

        $target=$savepath . $filename;
        $result=file_put_contents( $target, base64_decode( $image ) );


        header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK',true,200);
        header('Content-Type: text/plain');
        exit( $result ? sprintf( 'File uploaded & saved as %s', $target ) : sprintf( 'Unable to save %s',$filename ) );
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>HTML Canvas Image to PHP</title>
        <script>
        (function(options){
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(e){
                /*
                    generate a canvas with some sort of image - 
                    in this example a promo picture from the classic 
                    B-Horror film "The Blob"
                */
                var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
                var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
                var img=new Image();
                    img.src='/images/tmp/TheBlob.jpg';
                    img.onload=function(){
                        canvas.width=img.width;
                        canvas.height=img.height;
                        ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
                    }


                /* 
                    Button click event handler
                    create FormData Object and read the canvas data
                    then send via ajax to a PHP script ( in this case the same page )
                    to process the uploaded image.
                */
                function bindEvents(event){

                    var fd=new FormData();
                        fd.append('action','save');
                        fd.append('image', canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg').replace( /^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, '' ) );
                        fd.append('filename',img.src.split('/').pop() )

                    var ajax=function(url,data,callback){
                        var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                            if( this.readyState==4 && this.status==200 )callback.call( this, this.response );
                        };
                        xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
                        xhr.send( data );
                    };

                    var callback=function(r){
                        alert(r)
                    }

                    ajax.call( this, location.href, fd, callback );
                }


                document.getElementById('bttn').addEventListener( 'click', bindEvents, options );

            }, options );
        })({ passive:true, capture:false, once:false });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
        <input type='button' id='bttn' value='Upload & Save Image' />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: var ajax=function(url,data,callback).. data is coming from where? is it base64 image?

Comment: the `data` argument is `fd` ~ `FormData`

Comment: "Is it base64 image?" - Yes, take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL and notice, in the php, `base64_decode( $image )`